# Difference between creating indexes in Django using db_index=true and Class Meta: indexes=[ models.Index(fields=[col1, col2,..]),]

Tags: python, django, indexing

I was looking into how to create an index in Django. I came across two ways:

1. `Class Student(models.Model): name= models.CharField(........, db_index=True) age= models.CharField(........, db_index=True)`
2. `Class Student(models.Model): name= models.CharField(........) age= models.CharField(........) Class Meta:  indexes = [models.Index(name="first_index",fields=["name","age"],)]`

Can someone clarify what the difference between them is? Moreover, in the db_index=true method, is there a single index for all the fields with db_index=true ?

Comment: You probably want to look at [composite indexes](https://www.scaler.com/topics/sql/composite-index-in-sql/). I don't use django but I suspect the latter example is a composite index

Comment: In the first case you create 2 individual indexes, in the second case you create a combined index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter will make a *combined* index, so an index that takes the two fields, and makes a retrieval if both fields are specified efficient.

This means that if only `name` is given to filter on, the index will (likely) not be useful, if you only specify the `age`, this will be the same, only if you specify both `name` and `age` that index in case two will be useful.

It will however be more useful if you specify both when you have an index on the combination and it thus can easily find the `Student`(s) with that name and age. Otherwise it will probably look in both indexes, and then make a set of records that appear in both.

The two are however not mutually exclusive, you can make an index for `name`, for `age`, and for `name` and `age` combined with:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(name='name_age_index', fields=['name','age'],)]
```